# SQL query search by ID and get another attribute of the record

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

I'm working on a DB where I need to search MAX(ID), where ID is an autonumber, (basically the most recent record/last record) and then when found I want to get the receipt number. e.g.

receipt table

```
ID         DATE        Number
2          ###          1423
3          ###          1452
4          ###          1401
```

I'm currently retrieving Max(Number) but due to program requirement, most recent is not always the highest. So I want to retrieve the highest ID value then get the value of Number to increment. I tried nested queries but no results. Although I'm familiar with VBA, I'm not as good with complex queries and optimization.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `DMax` to get the maximum `ID` value from your table.  For example, in the Immediate window ...

```vb
? DMax("ID", "YourTable")
```

You can use that expression in a query to ask for the row with the highest `ID` value.

```sql
SELECT y.ID, y.DATE, y.Number
FROM YourTable AS y
WHERE y.ID=DMax('ID', 'YourTable');
```

But `DMax` is Access-specific.  If you want an approach which is portable to other databases you can use a subquery to retrieve the highest `ID` value.

```sql
SELECT y.ID, y.DATE, y.Number
FROM YourTable AS y
WHERE y.ID=(SELECT Max(ID) FROM YourTable);
```

Comment: I can use DMax however it returns the value of ID and not Number, also I think you cant use Max and DMax in WHERE predicate, thats whats cause the dilemma.

Comment: I created and tested both those queries with your sample data in Access 2007, and both returned the row where ID = 4, as expected.  If you want to see only `Number` in the result set, select only that field: `SELECT y.Number
FROM YourTable AS y
WHERE y.ID=DMax('ID', 'YourTable');`